# Neo4j feature or bug with search query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have recently updated neo4j from 2.1.7 to 2.2.5. I found out that query

```
Match (c:C) where id(c) = 111 with c Match (p:I{id: c.id}) return count(p)
```

worked fine in 2.1.7, but it performs very poor in 2.2.5 (100 times longer). I have all the indexes that are needed.
I modified this query to

```
Match (c:C) where id(c) = 111 with c.id as c_id Match (p:I{id: c_id}) return count(p)
```

and after this it works fine in 2.2.5
This two queries have different profile. But I'm not very expirienced with profiling.

UPDATED
One more strange thing is that if i use explain instead of profile - it works fast.

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ PROFILE Match (c:C) where id(c) = 10563822 with c Match (i:I{id: c.id}) return count(i);
==> +----------+
==> | count(i) |
==> +----------+
==> | 4551     |
==> +----------+
==> 1 row
==> 18257 ms
==> 
==> Compiler CYPHER 2.2
==> 
==> Planner COST
==> 
==> EagerAggregation
==>   |
==>   +Filter(0)
==>     |
==>     +CartesianProduct
==>       |
==>       +Filter(1)
==>       |  |
==>       |  +NodeByIdSeek
==>       |
==>       +NodeByLabelScan
==> 
==> +------------------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------------------+
==> |         Operator | EstimatedRows |    Rows |  DbHits | Identifiers |                   Other |
==> +------------------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------------------+
==> | EagerAggregation |            26 |       1 |       0 |    count(i) |                         |
==> |        Filter(0) |           652 |    4551 | 2522988 |        c, i |            i.id == c.id |
==> | CartesianProduct |          6521 | 1261494 |       0 |        c, i |                         |
==> |        Filter(1) |             0 |       1 |       1 |           c |                     c:C |
==> |     NodeByIdSeek |             1 |       1 |       1 |           c |                         |
==> |  NodeByLabelScan |       1261494 | 1261494 | 1261495 |           i |                      :I |
==> +------------------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------------------+
==> 
==> Total database accesses: 3784485

sh (?)$ PROFILE Match (c:C) where id(c) = 10563822 with c.id as c_id Match (i:I{id: c_id}) return count(i);
==> +----------+
==> | count(i) |
==> +----------+
==> | 4551     |
==> +----------+
==> 1 row
==> 64 ms
==> 
==> Compiler CYPHER 2.2
==> 
==> Planner COST
==> 
==> EagerAggregation
==>   |
==>   +Apply
==>     |
==>     +Projection
==>     |  |
==>     |  +Filter
==>     |    |
==>     |    +NodeByIdSeek
==>     |
==>     +NodeIndexSeek
==> 
==> +------------------+---------------+------+--------+-------------+---------------------+
==> |         Operator | EstimatedRows | Rows | DbHits | Identifiers |               Other |
==> +------------------+---------------+------+--------+-------------+---------------------+
==> | EagerAggregation |             1 |    1 |      0 |    count(i) |                     |
==> |            Apply |             1 | 4551 |      0 |  c, c_id, i |                     |
==> |       Projection |             0 |    1 |      1 |     c, c_id |                c.id |
==> |           Filter |             0 |    1 |      1 |           c |                 c:C |
==> |     NodeByIdSeek |             1 |    1 |      1 |           c |                     |
==> |    NodeIndexSeek |             1 | 4551 |   4552 |           i |              :I(id) |
==> +------------------+---------------+------+--------+-------------+---------------------+
==> 
==> Total database accesses: 4555
```

Comment: There are a couple of behaviors like this when the COST PLANNER in Neo4j 2.2.x does not use indexes. These behaviors are being removed in upcoming releases, you can try to prefix your query with PLANNER RULE in order to use the schema indexes.

Comment: can you share your profiles for both queries?

Comment: `PROFILE` not only does profiling, but it actually also runs the query. `EXPLAIN` just does profiling. That is why is was much faster :-).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough knowledge of neo4j internals to know why your query is slower (the `CartesianProduct` step seems a red flag) in more recent versions, but here is a logically equivalent query that seems like it should be much faster:

```
START c = node(111)
MATCH (p:I { id: c.id })
RETURN count(p)
```

Here is the profile:

```
+------------------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
|         Operator | Rows | DbHits |                                              Identifiers |                 Other |
+------------------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
|     ColumnFilter |    1 |      0 |                                                 count(p) | keep columns count(p) |
| EagerAggregation |    1 |      0 |   INTERNAL_AGGREGATE51b25e53-027d-439b-9046-c1a2a6b0fe70 |                       |
|           Filter |    0 |      0 |                                                     c, p |          p.id == c.id |
|         NodeById |    0 |      0 |                                                     c, p |    Literal(List(111)) |
|      NodeByLabel |    0 |      1 |                                                        p |                    :I |
+------------------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

**NOTE: This should be considered a temporary workaround, as `START` has been deprecated, and I do not know how long this kind of usage will continue to be supported.**